# View transitions between Android activies in Application Insights exported from App Center

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

We have a Xamarin.Android app where our MainLauncher activity in OnCreate has:

```
AppCenter.Start(AppSecret, typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

We have configured App Center to export data to Application Insights.

We are currently using v1.12 of the Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics module.

In Application Insights we can see the events we are logging explicitly, but can we somewhere see how users are navigating between activities? Or do we have to log this explicitly also?

Comment: how are you defining "activities" in this case?  are they not treated as events? (I guess it depends on what appcenter sends for you in those cases?)  if they *are* events, you could use the flows tool to look at how users navigate? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-flows

Comment: (I've also forwarded this to a person internally in appcenter who might know more details)

Comment: @JohnGardner Activities in Android are the screens from which the app is build. The base class is called Activity.